# In layman's terms vs. simply put

Tags: phrase-choice, formality

In the following sentence:

> **Simply put**, the impacts of global warming are going to be more evident in not-too-distant future.

Can I use `In layman's terms` instead of simply put?

> **In layman's terms**, the impacts of global warming are going to be more evident in not-too-distant future.

Which one is more formal and academic and which one is more likely to be used in speaking?

Comment: You can use it if you have previously  been discussing the subject in highly technical language (that a 'layman' - a non-scientist - might not understand).

Comment: I think you should be careful about assuming that these two usages are "equivalent". To my mind, ***simply put*** implies *potentially inaccurate* simplifications. That's because the thing being described might be *inherently* complex, and thus incapable of being accurately represented in a "simple" way. But ***in layman's terms*** just means "avoiding jargon" (you could still communicate very complex concepts using just "layman's terms").